# How to access parameter from parent report within child report? SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have a parent report where I modified its actions so that when you click on a particular column, the report goes to a different report. I pass in a column value to the child report. I am now trying to make the default value of a parameter from within the child report use the parameter from the parent report. How do I do access it?

Comment: Pass all the parameters you need from Parent report to child report.

Comment: Yeah but how do I use them? Where do I access the parameters from the parent report from within the child report?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to create a parameter with the exact same name in the child report. It will automatically inherit the parameter from the parent report if the name is the same. You don't have to set a "default value" for the parameter pointing to the passed in parameter. My mistake is that I thought you could name the parameters differently.